# ECharts Yaxis issue

Tags: echarts, yaxis

I have a `ECharts` line chart where, based on some condition, the series can or can't have the `markline`. The problem is that, if the actual maximum yaxis value is less then a markline y value, not all the markline will be shown.

I tried to set manually the min/max of my yaxis but nothing changes.

This is how the axis conditions are defined in the option:

```
axis:[
     {
         scale: true
     }],
xAxis: [{
          type: "time"
       }],
yAxis: [{
           type: "value",
           axisLabel: {
                formatter: "{value} ° C"
                },
           scale: true
         }]
```

and this is how I set the min/max yaxis values:

```
termoLineCharts[index].yAxis.min = minYvalue - 15;
termoLineCharts[index].yAxis.max = maxYValue + 15;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution: the `yaxis` option is an array, so in order to set the min and max value I had to do this

```
optionLineCharts[index].yAxis[0].min = minYvalue;
optionLineCharts[index].yAxis[0].max = maxYValue;
```